# Rewriting a long T- SQL query in a simpler way (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following T-SQL query that works but I am wondering if it can be written in a more elegant way?

```
SELECT *
FROM [2021_history]
WHERE FORMAT([Current Baseline DATE], 'yyyy-MM') = '2021-01' 
  AND FORMAT ([Reporting Date], 'yyyy-MM') = '2021-02'

UNION

SELECT *
FROM .[2021_history]
WHERE FORMAT([Current Baseline DATE], 'yyyy-MM') = '2021-02' 
  AND FORMAT([Reporting Date], 'yyyy-MM') = '2021-03'

UNION

SELECT *
FROM [2021_history]
WHERE FORMAT([Current Baseline DATE], 'yyyy-MM') = '2021-03' 
  AND FORMAT([Reporting Date], 'yyyy-MM') = '2021-04'

etc...etc...

UNION

SELECT *
FROM [2021_history]
WHERE FORMAT([Current Baseline DATE], 'yyyy-MM') = '2021-12' 
  AND FORMAT([Reporting Date], 'yyyy-MM') = '2021-11'
```

Comment: Should the last UNION be for `2020-12`, since `2021-12` hasn't happened yet? And if that is correct, do you want to include `2021-01` as well?

Comment: I am just anticipating, right now I need to update it each month and I want to avoid this.

Comment: Right now if up to April

Comment: Rule of thumb, *never* compare dates by turning them into strings. Use proper date comparison functions.

Comment: Learn the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. It can be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to filter using the dates.  You can simplify this to:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM [2021_history] h
WHERE [Current Baseline DATE] >= '2021-01-01' AND
      [Current Baseline DATE] < '2021-02-01' AND
      DATEDIFF(MONTH, [Current Baseline DATE], [Reporting Date]) = 1;
```

Note:  This can use an index on `[Current Baseline DATE]` (which your current query cannot).  If you had an index on `[Reporting Date]`, the logic could be modified for that as well.

The `UNION` removes duplicates.  So if you actually have duplicated rows (which seems like a data problem to me), then you would use `SELECT DISTINCT h.*`.

Comment: Beat me by a minute or so (timestamps are different, but your answer looked much different when I started ;)

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help! Resolved.